# PowerShell to find Trademark

Tags: powershell, unicode

I am trying to use `Select-String` to find the trademark symbol in docx files - they Unicode for the symbol is `0x00AE`, but the regular expression (that does work in say RegExpal) `\u00AE` does not work
I tried just this simple thing:

```
Select-String -Path *.docx "\u00AE"
```

I am a bit of a newb and will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `Select-String` ([documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)) searches for strings in *plain-text* files.

A DOCX file is *not* plain text, but a bunch of XML files inside a ZIP container. It's a binary file, and due to compression won't even contain the characters in the text of the document.

What you probably want is a library that can read OOXML documents; you would then search in the text returned by the library.

In particular, look at the [`Select-OpenXmlString`](http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/powertools-for-open-xml-2-0-cmdlets.aspx) command from the [Power Tools for Open XML](http://powertools.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex. [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/03/19/announcing-the-release-of-powertools-for-open-xml-v1-1.aspx) gives a description and usage example:

> Select-OpenXmlString[...] has similar functionality to the Select-String cmdlet that comes with PowerShell.

In particular, to use it to search for a string like `"\u00AE"`,

> You can use the –List parameter of Select-OpenXmlString to retrieve a list of all documents with specific content.   In this directory, I have a lot of Open XML documents, and want to find all documents that mention France.
>
> ```
> Select-OpenXmlString *.docx -simpleMatch France -List | Select-Object Filename
> ```